# Thread Scheduling in ROS

Tags: ros, libroscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

Anybody had an idea about thread scheduling in ROS?
Suppose I have a node which spawns multiple threads. How ROS handle scheduling of these user defined threads?
Can anybody spread some light on these topics.

Thanks in advance
Murali krishna

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268376/thread-scheduling-in-ros/) by [mkreddy477](https://answers.ros.org/users/29390/mkreddy477/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2017-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS generally does not mess with threads you spawn (i.e. change priorities or so). This is up to the operating system and you can use standard operating system facilities to do so (for instance setting priority to SCHED_FIFO or so).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mkreddy477](https://answers.ros.org/users/29390/mkreddy477/) on 2017-08-11**:
Thanks for the clarification

**Comment by [anonymous53964](https://answers.ros.org/users/53964/anonymous53964/) on 2020-05-01**:
What is the difference between nodelets and threads